# Convert pandas data rame rows to couple lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

## Question UPDATED

How to convert data frame like:

```
df = 

 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11

 1   2   3   4   5   6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 7   8   9  10  11  12 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
13  14  15  16  17  18 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

To the list exactly like this (with NaN skipping):

```
df_list = 

    [array([[ 1, 2],
            [ 3, 4],
            [ 5, 6]]), array([[ 7, 8],
            [ 9, 10],
            [ 11, 12]]), array([[ 13, 14],
            [ 15, 16],
            [ 17, 18]])]
```

I have tried `df1.values.tolist()` but it does not give me couples

[future data frame should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AM5W.png)

Comment: Why would you want a list like this? This seems like a completely arbitrary output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match you exact output:

```
[df.loc[i].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2) for i in df.index]
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]], dtype=int64), array([[ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]], dtype=int64), array([[13, 14],
        [15, 16],
        [17, 18]], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: Works good, but when a want to build a dataframe from it `pd.DataFrame(df)` I get `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input`

Comment: What should you dataframe look like?  `pd.DataFrame(zip(*[df.loc[i].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2) for i in df.index]))`

Answer (score 1):

Specify how many items you want in each group, and use `numpy`'s `reshape`

---

```
n = 2

df.to_numpy().reshape(df.shape[0], -1, n)
```

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]],

       [[13, 14],
        [15, 16],
        [17, 18]]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: If you check my desired output it is a bit different. And moreover, pd.DataFrame(df) is not working

Comment: You can't have a higher than 2 dimensional dataframe.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].